# how to wrap and unwrap html control with a div dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i am generating html control dynamically and now i want to wrap the html content in a div dynamically using jquery.

Example: dynamically generated control is

```
<input type='text' value='default' id='text1'/>
```

should be wrapped as

```
<div class='outerdiv'>
  <input type='text' value='default' id='text1'/>
  <span class='handle'></span>
</div>
```

i tried with

```
$('#text1').wrap("<div class='outerdiv'><span class='handle'></span></div>");
```

and for unwrap i use

```
$('#text1').unwrap();
```

but i am unable to get what i expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.wrap()` to enclose it in a div, and then `.after()` or `.append()` to add the span.

```
$('#text1').wrap("<div class='outerdiv'></div>").after("<span class='handle'></span>");
```

To unwrap and delete, locate and `.remove()` the span before you unwrap:

```
$('#text1').next().remove().end().unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. it works for wrapping but for unwrap span content stil remains.

Comment: Have you tried just browsing through the [jQuery traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to see what you can use?

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
$('#text1').wrap('<div class="outerdiv"></div>').after('<span class="handle"></span>');
```